# How do I get the text of the attribute value in an input tag using C++?

Tags: html, c++, innerhtml, atl, innertext

I have an input tag

```
<input class= " " size = " " read-only=" " value=" ">
```

(I get this when I do a `get_innerHtml()` on an `IHTMLELEMENT` object).

The library used is ATL.
I need to extract the text present in the value. Is there a way in which i can retrieve the text using an api?

Investigation Details:

I have tried using the `getAttribute()` api with the property as "value". This returns me a value "I4=0" in the variant. The element under question is a "list-item". With Tag as "LI". `Get_innerText` api gives me a garbage value.
 Note: Outer Html value is:

```
<li class=" "id= " "><input class= " " size= " " read-only=" " value=" "></li>
```

Here is the code:

```
CComBSTR bsValue = NULL;
pHtmlElement->get_innerText(&bsValue);
char* innerText = convertBSTRToCharPtr(bsValue);
CString cstring(innerText);
```

Comment: How and where do you get this? What library are you using? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hope this is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getAttribute() api on the IHtmlElement using the property as "value".

```
                CComBSTR bsProperty;
                bsProperty = "value";
                pChild->getAttribute(bsProperty,0,&vtVariant);
                bsValue1 = vtVariant.bstrVal;
```